# Populate dropdown 2 using dropdown1 in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My html :

```
<select ng-controller="category"  ng-model="selectedTestAccount" ng-options="c.category for c in categories track by c.categoryID" ></select>
<select ng-controller="subcatgory"  ng-model="selectedTestAccount1" ng-options="c.subcategory for c in subcategories track by c.subcategoryID"></select>
```

My json will look like:

json1:

```
category: "Restaurants"categoryID: "1"
```

json2:

```
category: "Restaurants"categoryID: "1"subcategory: "European"subcategoryID: "1"
category: "Restaurants"categoryID: "1"subcategory: "Food Carts"subcategoryID: "17"
```

i want two dropdowns to be created. One for first json which will display categories.
on selecting the first category i want subcategories to be listed from second json. How to make first dropdown as mandatory.
    Can anyone helpme with this

Comment: Give a me a few minutes, just creating a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have created you a [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1bT3f1WlsUYgQdU03aFL?p=preview)

The key is the `$watch` which looks at the selected value (`ng-model`) of the first list then changes the values for the second list based on that new value.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedCategory', function(newValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subCategories.length; i++){
    if ($scope.subCategories[i].name === newValue){
      $scope.selectedSubCategoryValues = $scope.subCategories[i].values;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to:

1. add the `required` attribute on the first select
2. put an empty `<option></option>` inside the select (otherwise the select has already a default option which satisfy the requirement)

Here's the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/n5568q6o/1/

Comment: I want to select the dropdowns dynamically. i.e., if i select category 2 in dropdown 2 , i want to list only the subcategories for that particular category

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watch to watch the first object. If that changes change the array for the second one.
This will change the options according to the options you want for that.